# How to turn off auto duration calculation is MS project 2010?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010, schedule

I tried File -> option -> Schedule -> Calculation after edit -> Off

And Task mode -> manual scheduled

I want to set start date at 12/01/09 and end date at 03/03/09 but I want to set the duration to be 182 hours.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Change your task to 'fixed duration.'  Load the number of days you need in the duration column.  Because you made your task fixed duration, those days will remain fixed.  (In your example, one of the resources you will need to make this work is a time machine.)

Then, load 182 hours in the work column.  Since the task is fixed duration and you hardcoded 182 hours, then resource utilization will auto calculate.

Comment: I found funny the time machine reference, but I guess it depends on the UK / US notation. From 01/Dec/09 to 03/Mar/09 a time machine would be definitely required, but from 12/Jan/09 to 03/Mar/09 it's ok - there are 50 days between then, 1200h total.

Comment: Ha!  You're right!  That was my ethnocentricity at play.  My apologies.